# Why does Open Graph Actions with "Map" display no longer display routes on the web?

Tags: dictionary, facebook-opengraph, routes

This have been the case for both my own app as well as other apps for some days. The IOS FB app still shows routes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was just a fluke during FB transitioning to a new display (?).